# ASP.Net Redirection with Specific Extension

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I need to redirect 404 pages that have an extension of CFM (ColdFusion). The old site was run under ColdFusion and now is a pure ASP.Net 4.0 site. The site is not MVC. I would like to take the parameters that are passed and direct to the new page.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming you want a redirect rather than a rewrite? If so then a custom 404 page (e.g., 404.asp) should do the job as @atticae writes below.

Comment: I'm doing at 404 page redirect right now. I'm trying local and using the following: http://localhost:58940/index.cfm?go=location.a&PID=675. The system only catches the %20index.cfm. What I need to catch is the index.cfm and the go= location at a minimum and ideally also the PID parameter as well. If I change the CFM to ASPX it does redirect but the parameters are there. If I leave as CFM the system gives a IIS default page redirect and not the one defined within the website itself.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with a custom 404 page but IIS puts the following into the query string of a custom 404: "404;http://yoursite.com/yourpage.cfm?go=xyz". You should be able to grab the query string from that and manually process the parameters to pass them on to the redirect. Another option would be to get the IIS URL Rewrite module, which allows for complicated redirection schemes (i.e., it does both rewriting and redirecting).

Answer (score 1):

Just let ASP.NET redirect the request to a custom 404 page and check for the file extension there.
Read out the file extension, check for CFM and do a 301 (Moved permanently) redirection via codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but could you just take the whole address and do the string manipulation to check whether the website address contains ColdFusion extension and after it pass the parameters as a QueryString to the suitable address?

String manipulation would be helpful especially if parameters from the ColdFusion URL match the ones needed for .NET URL.